# how to password check without using isdigit() and any like these methods?

Tags: python

```
def password(passw):

alphabet = [ 'a', 'b','c','d','e','f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q','r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
upperalp = [ 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
digit = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']


n = True

if len(passw) < 8:
    print("Lenght should be at least 8")
    n = False

if not any(alphabet for char in passw):
    print("Password should have at least one lowercase")
    n = False
if not any(upperalp for char in passw):
    print("Password should have at least one uppercase")
    n = False
if not any(digit for char in passw):
    print("Password should have at least one numeral")
    n = False

if len(passw) > 20:
    print("Password should be less than 20 characters")
    n = False

if n:
    return n
```

def main():

```
passw = input("enter password: ")

if (password(passw)):
    print("Password is valid")
else:
    print("Invalid password")
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

the program skips the alphabet and upperalp conditions. It just reads the length of the password entered.

Comment: `if not any(char in alphabet for char in passw)` instead of `if not any(alphabet for char in passw)`, similarly for other conditions.

Comment: `if ord(char) in range(48, 58)` to check if character is digit or not

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASCII character code to check these conditions:

```
def check_password(password):
    check = False
    if len(password)<8:
        print("length must be more than 7 character")
        return check

    if len(password)>20:
        print("length must be less than 20 character")
        return check    
    dic = {'upper':[],'lower':[], 'specialchar':[], 'number':[]}
    for charc in password:
        if ord(charc) in list(range(97, 123)):
            dic['lower'].append(charc)
        elif ord(charc) in list(range(65, 91)):
            dic['upper'].append(charc)
        elif ord(charc) in list(range(48, 58)):
            dic['number'].append(charc)
        else:
            dic['specialchar'].append(charc)

    for index, value in dic.items():
        if len(value)<1:
            print("at least 1 {} character".format(index))
            return check
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way (in my opinion):

```
print("Type the password you want to check.")
password = input()

uppercase_count = 0
lowercase_count = 0
digit_count = 0

# length more then 8 char:
if len(password) < 8:
    print('length should be at least 8 characters')

# length less then 20 char:
if len(password) > 20:
    print('password should be less than 20 characters')

# uppercase
for i in range(len(password)):
    if 'A' <= password[i] <= 'Z':
        uppercase_count += 1
print("uppercase letters in the password: " + str(uppercase_count))

# lowercase
for i in range(len(password)):
    if 'a' <= password[i] <= 'z':
        lowercase_count += 1
print("lowercase letters in the password: " + str(lowercase_count))

# digit
for i in range(len(password)):
    if '0' <= password[i] <= '9':
        digit_count += 1
print("digits in the password: " + str(digit_count))
```

With small improvements:

```
print("Type the password you want to check.")
password = input()

uppercase_count = 0
lowercase_count = 0
digit_count = 0
correct_password = None

# uppercase
for i in range(len(password)):
    if 'A' <= password[i] <= 'Z':
        uppercase_count += 1
print("uppercase letters in the password: " + str(uppercase_count))

# lowercase
for i in range(len(password)):
    if 'a' <= password[i] <= 'z':
        lowercase_count += 1
print("lowercase letters in the password: " + str(lowercase_count))

# digit
for i in range(len(password)):
    if '0' <= password[i] <= '9':
        digit_count += 1
print("digits in the password: " + str(digit_count))


if any([uppercase_count < 1, lowercase_count < 1, digit_count < 1, len(password) > 20, len(password) < 8]):
    print("Password is BAD")
else:
    print("Password is OK")
```